# How remove buffer limitation in stm32 controller?

Tags: android, usb, stm32

I have an stm32 microcontroller and try to connect to it in Android with a USB library. All of the things are good and can send data and receive data from stm32, but the receiving data is not complete and only receive 20 bytes from the first packet.

I do it via USB UsbEndpoint. Original packet size is 1024 bytes but receiving data are 1024 with a null value. I have read, max packet size is 64 bytes, Is that right?

PS: My main problem is in Android, because in Realterm software, data is being received completely.

Comment: What kind of device class are you using? What is the transfer type? What are the frameworks / libraries you use on Android & STM32? For USB FS, max packet size is 64 bytes for bulk transfers, but a transaction can consists of many packets, so it's possible to transfer 1024 (and more) bytes.

Comment: @Tagli library is USB API for Android, the microcontroller is stm32f103ret6 and I use STM32 USB FS Device Driver for STM32F10x that was published by STMicroelectronics

Comment: @Tagli My main problem is in Android because, in Realterm software, data received completely